# commandline search path in python

Tags: python, cmd, path

I have a python script, called runme.py. it lives in a shared space. My users need to run runme from a different directory. I'd rather that they don't have to type in the relative or absolute path to runme.py whenever the run it.

I'd like them to be able to just type:

```
python runme.py [arguments]
```

and python will figure out where runme.py is via a path-like variable.

My users are all using DOS command line, but I'm more familiar with unix, so I'll use that syntax.

I know that $PATH (%PATH%) isn't what I want. I'm pretty sure that $PYTHONPATH also isn't what I want. Is there a variable that IS what I want?

I know that I can write a runme.bat wrapper file that is executable, so $PATH is what I need, but there are multiple of these top level scripts, and I'd rather not have to maintain multiple wrappers. (In unix I could do fancy things with the wrappers all being symlinked to the same wrapper, but not in DOS)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could add the directory where `runme.py` is located to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and then run it as `python -m runme [arguments]`

Comment: If your file association is correct then you should not need the `python` prefix providing your filenames end in `.py`.   You could have a `.bat` file which manipulated the PATH to make sure your python directories are there - but then of course you need the `.bat` file to be in a directory that's in %PATH%.  I'm assuming you don't want to install it somewhere like `Windows`.

Comment: @cdarke you are correct. I don't need the "python" and if I just try to run the .py file it finds it, and runs with python, and everything works! Please add  this as an answer so I can accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An advanced solution would be to follow [this guide](https://packaging.python.org/) to build a standard python package.  Users would use `pip` to install the package from pypi or from a wheel file you will supply them.  When packaging your module, specify [`console-scripts`](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#console-scripts) to create command line scripts available from any command line console.

Comment: The users aren't that computer savy... the simpler the better.